# How to show directories before files in Finder?

Tags: finder, switching

I would like to have windows in the Finder sort directories before files, in the manner of Microsoft Windows' Explorer as well as Linux KDE.

I tried following [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/67100/force-your-mac-to-put-folders-on-top-of-files-windows-style/) but it did not yield the desired outcome, specifically some directories had contents sorted that way but some had files first then directories and some were still mixed.  Also, I would like to know what the difference is between `sorting` and `arranging` in the `Show View Options` screen.

Comment: Did you `killall Finder` from terminal?

Comment: yep and still doesn't sort after reopening

Answer (score 2):

If you want to view things in a more Microsoft Windows-like fashion, there are several third-party commercial utilities that can provide more options. I do not know which of these will provide the exact layout you want, but you can download trial versions of one or more of the following:

[RAGE Macintosh Explorer](http://www.ragesw.com/products/explorer.html) (This app is free)

[Binary Age Total Finder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com)

[CocoaTech Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/pathfinder/)

[St. Clair Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/index.html) (for Open and Save dialog boxes)

Comment: i wouldn't attribute this style to Windows only, e.g. my Fedora KDE filesystem browsers (e.g. Thunar and Nautilus) do it that way also.